# How can I pass flask db query all results to template so jquery can access it also?

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, html, flask

I'm trying to figure out how I can access flask db query all data passed to template from jquery function. I have a db table containing customer_name and customer_phone_number. I pass this to template via flask view db query all. I iterate this and load customer_name into dropdown, no problems here! I'm using jquery to monitor dropdown selection and want to load customer_phone_number into text input field when customer_name is selected. Something like this:

flask view:

```
@auth.route('/order/add', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def order_add():
    form = OrderForm()
    custs = Customer.query.filter_by(type_is_retail=False).all()
    return render_template('auth/orders/order_add_test2.html', 
    custs=custs,  form=form, title='New Order')
```

html template:

```
<div class="form-group form-group-comp_name col-xs-12" id="wholesale_set"
       style="display: none;"> <!-- SET display to none -->
      <label class="control-label">Company Name</label>
      <select class="form-control " id="comp_name" name="cust" type="text">
        <option>Add New Company</option>
        <option disabled>----------------------------</option>
        <option hidden disabled selected value>Select Company</option>
      {% if custs %}        
        {% for cust in custs %}
        <option>{{ cust.lname }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
      {% endif %}
      </select>
    </div>

<div class="form-group form-group-pn_set col-xs-12" id="pn_set"
     style="display: none;"> <!-- SET display to none -->
      <label class="control-label" for="pn">Phone Number</label>
      <input class="form-control" id="pn" name="pn" maxlength="12"
             style="text-align: center;" type="text"/>
</div>
```

jquery:

```
$('#comp_name').on('change', function() {
var cust_pn;
for cust in custs {  <---------------------------------
    if ($(this).val() == cust.customer_name) { <------- Here is issue!
        $('#pn').val() = cust.customer_phone_number; <-
    }
}
});
```

Looking for proper syntax to iterate over db query in Jquery. It doesn't seem necessary to implement AJAX to go back to flask to get another db query, just for Jquery. 
Is there a way to pass the orignal db query to Jquery initally? Or access the original query via Jquery also?

using answer below, if I:

```
var custs = {{ custs }};
```

this line prevents my other (unrelated to this question) jquery functions from working!

but if I:

```
var custs; 
$('#comp_name').on('change', function() { 
custs = "{{ custs }}"; 
alert(custs); 
});
```

then alert shows:

```
[&lt;Customer1&gt;,&lt;Customer3&gt;]
```

which is the correct customer numbers that I need access to, but doesn't show _name or _phone_number that I can access or reference.
This seems to be getting me closer to my objective, however!
How can I use this properly to access custs.company_name and custs.phone_number?
I'm not opposed to using AJAX if that is only way, I just don't think that is the most efficient way seeing how the data I need hass already been passed to the template. Should I also pass the same data a different way for jquery to access it also at the same time I pass it to the template? Instead of passing data to template then firing jquery to go back to flask view to get the same data (maybe wrapped in a different coat!) and bring it back to jquery!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I figured out a solution! Maybe not the best way, but it works for me!

I changed html from:

```
<div class="form-group form-group-comp_name col-xs-12" id="wholesale_set"
   style="display: none;"> <!-- SET display to none -->
  <label class="control-label">Company Name</label>
  <select class="form-control " id="comp_name" name="cust" type="text">
    <option>Add New Company</option>
    <option disabled>----------------------------</option>
    <option hidden disabled selected value>Select Company</option>
  {% if custs %}        
    {% for cust in custs %}
    <option>{{ cust.lname }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
  </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group form-group-pn_set col-xs-12" id="pn_set"
 style="display: none;"> <!-- SET display to none -->
  <label class="control-label" for="pn">Phone Number</label>
  <input class="form-control" id="pn" name="pn" maxlength="12"
         style="text-align: center;" type="text"/>
```

to:

```
<div class="form-group form-group-comp_name col-xs-12" id="wholesale_set"
   style="display: none;"> <!-- SET display to none -->
  <label class="control-label">Company Name</label>
  <select class="form-control " id="comp_name" name="cust" type="text">
    <option>Add New Company</option>
    <option disabled>----------------------------</option>
    <option hidden disabled selected value>Select Company</option>
  {% if custs %}        
    {% for cust in custs %}
    <option value="{{ cust.pn }}>{{ cust.lname }}</option> <-------HERE-----
    {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
  </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group form-group-pn_set col-xs-12" id="pn_set"
 style="display: none;"> <!-- SET display to none -->
  <label class="control-label" for="pn">Phone Number</label>
  <input class="form-control" id="pn" name="pn" maxlength="12"
         style="text-align: center;" type="text"/>
```

I added a 'value' tag to the option, so as the template loads the {{ cust.lname  }} into the dropdown, it also loads the {{ cust.pn }} for that particular selection.

Then I changed my Jquery from:

```
$('#comp_name').on('change', function() {
    var cust_pn;
    for cust in custs {
        if ($(this).val() == cust.customer_name) {
        $('#pn').val() = cust.customer_phone_number;
        }
    }
});
```

To:

```
$('#comp_name').on('change', function() {
    $('#pn').val($(this).val());
});
```

Works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

As you don't want to use AJAX request, so AFAIK the only way you can achieve this is to dump the data in JSON in javascript as.

```
<script>
var custs = {{ custs }};
// other part of code
// here you can perform what ever you want
</script>
```

The data should confirm JSON standard.

```
[{
        "customer_name": "Test Name",
        "customer_phone_number": "+140123445"
    },
    {
        "customer_name": "Test Name2",
        "customer_phone_number": "+1401234456"
    }
]
```

EDIT:
If `"`, `'` and others are getting escaped then mark the string as safe using `safe` filter as below,

`var custs = {{ cust_json | safe }}`;

Comment: adding var custs = {{ custs }}; to my script stops all other jquery from functioning!

Comment: The problem is due to escape the filter which escapes `"` or `'` to their corresponding HTML code.